# Can anyone explain me the meaning of read function in the following code in haskell

Tags: haskell

```
toDigits n = map (\c -> read [c]) (show n)
```

I'm unable to understand the meaning of read function in the above code

Comment: read parses the 1-char string into another datastructure. This can be anything. But here it is probably an `Int`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Note**: all `toDigits` here only work with positive numbers (zero included), and will error on negative numbers.

`read` has signature:

```
read :: Read a => String -> a
```

So based on the signature we can say that if a type `a` is `Read a`, then it turns a `String` into that `a`. In natural language it means that it *parses* a textual representation of an object into that object. For instance it can parse `"\"foo\""` into the String `"foo"`. Or it can parse `"23"` into the integer `23`. It is the output type that determines into what we parse the elements, but based on the function, it has probably some type signature `toDigits :: Int -> Int`.

Nowe we still have to understand how the function works. `show :: Show a => a -> String` is actually the opposite of `read`: it converts an object into a textual representation. So `23` is for instance converted into `"23"`, a `String`.

So first we convert a number, for instance `1425` into `"1425"`. A `String` is a *list* of `Char`s, or more formal `type String = [Char]`. So that means we can perform a `map` on it, and `map` will thus process each `Char` of the `String`, one at a time.

Now for each char `c`, we first construct a list `[c]`. Why do we do that? To make it a `String`. Since a `String` is a list of chars. A list with one character is equal to a string with that character. Next we call read on the 1-char String, to turn it into whatever we like.

This means that `toDigits` has as most generic type:

```
toDigits :: (Show a, Read b) => a -> [b]
```

Note that according to this signature, we are not bounded by the fact that `a` should be a number, nor that the output should be numbers. As long as the textual representation of the `a` object can be split into 1-char strings that can be parsed indivudually into object of `b`, we are fine. However in reality, it will probably only make sense if both `a` and `b` are `Integral`, so:

```
toDigits :: (Show a, Read b, Integral a, Integral b) => a -> [b]
```

A final note is that we can make the implementation a bit more elegant, like:

```
toDigits :: (Show a, Read b, Integral a, Integral b) => a -> [b]
toDigits = map (read . pure) . show
```

We can further restrict the output type to `Int`, since an `Int` is guaranteed to have all numbers between (and including) 0 and 9, and construct:

```
import Data.Char(digitToInt)

toDigits :: (Show a, Integral a) => a -> [Int]
toDigits = map digitToInt . show
```

That being said, the function makes some assumptions: for instance that all numbers will have a textual representation that is the decimal notation. This is not per se guaranteed: I could construct my own number system, and decide to construct a show that for instance uses the unary system (although that is probably not a good idea). This makes it a bit a *dangerous* approach: you rely on some assumptions that are not guaranteed. Furthermore this

We can use the `div` and `mod` to calculate the digits. For instance like:

```
toDigits :: Integral a => a -> [a]
toDigits 0 = [0]
toDigits n | n < 0 = error "Negative number!"
           | otherwise = step [] n
    where step xs 0 = xs
          step xs d = step ((mod d 10):xs) (div d 10)
```

furthermore we dropped the `Show a` type constraint, so integrals that do not have such `show` can still be handled.

Comment: [`digitToInt`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:digitToInt) is even more elegant than `read . pure`.

Comment: Thanks...it indeed helps a lot... Also i read that read functions can only give us numerical types such as an Int or a double...cam you explain more about it

Comment: @DaminShah: no, `read` can produce all types for which the type constraint `Read` holds.